# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Using Object Output & Input Stream

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Been stuck on this for a while now and have no clue. I'm trying to write some objects to file for an app I'm making but keep getting the file not found exception. Here are the methods for write & read that I'm using.

I get the log to say read is starting, but after that I get the error and get no more logs.

```
private void loadData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Will run and load all data from the config file into the app's memory
    Log.d("READ:", "reading starting");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("config");
    ObjectInputStream oIS = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
    Object[] output = new Object[4];

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        output[i] = oIS.readObject();
        Log.d("READ:", output[i].toString());
    }

    oIS.close();
    fileInputStream.close();

    return;
}

public void writeData() throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("config", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);
    Log.d("writeData:", "streamsOpened");

    oOut.writeInt(this.targetINR);
    oOut.writeObject(this.inrReadings);
    oOut.writeObject(this.weeklyDoses);
    oOut.writeObject(this.alarmTime);
    Log.d("writeData:", "objectsWritten");
    oOut.close();
    fOut.close();
    Log.d("writeData:", "Streams closed, write finished");

    return;
}
```

**Heres the code that calls these methods.**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

    inrReadings = new HashMap<Calendar, Integer>();
    weeklyDoses = new HashMap<Calendar, Integer>();
    TextView debug = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView) ;
    debug.setText("Vars init");

    targetINR = 2;
    inrReadings.put(Calendar.getInstance(), 2);
    weeklyDoses.put(Calendar.getInstance(), 2);
    alarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();;

    isStoragePermissionGranted();

 /*   try {
        writeData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        debug.setText(debug.getText() + " errorWrite");
        Log.d("writeData:", "ioException");
    }

    try {
        loadData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("readData:", "ioException");
        debug.setText(debug.getText() + " errorRead");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("readData:", "ioException");
        debug.setText(debug.getText() + " errorClassNotFound");
    }
```

*/
    }

Here are the two permision check methods:

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("Perms:","Permission is granted now");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v("Perms:","Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v("Perms:","Permission is granted already");
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.v("Perms:","Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);

        // User has granted the access. Now you can initiate the file writing.
        try {
            writeData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.v("Write:", "ioError");
        }

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    }
                });

        try {
            loadData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("Read:", "ioError");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("Read:", "ClassNotFound");
        }
    }
}
```

Full error log here: https://pastebin.com/dhxnXyUg

New error log: https://pastebin.com/Nq0Kh1Au

**Edit:

Fixed it with a work around, see answers.**

Comment: I'm not an Android guy, but don't you have to use `openFileInput()` rather than `new FileInputStream()`? NB This problem has nothing to do with object streams, as the stack trace will show you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything, my LogCat has changed since I've done some of the previous suggested things so you can reload that if you want. I've uploaded the LogCat with your changes here:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Nq0Kh1Au

Comment: I don't see any errors at all in your new log.

Comment: No errors, but the files aren't being read. I don't think the write function is even getting called because the Log.v isn't being shown in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it in the end, without implementing the onRequestPermision() etc. I just simplified the object write by getting it only write one object (an array of objects). That array has all the values needed stored inside it. Bit of a workaround but it simplifies the writing process!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not added the following permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you are using the latest version of Android SDK in your device, then you have to request for permission from the user as well. Here's how you can request the permission to write external storage from user.

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);

        // User has granted the access. Now you can initiate the file writing.
        writeData();
    }
}
```

**Update**

I can see that you are trying to access the file immediately after the file is created. In case of doing that, you need to scan the file before you access the newly created file.

```
// Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
// immediately available to the user.
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
        new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
            }
        });
```

I think you need to modify your `writeData` function like the following.

```
public void writeData() throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("config", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);
    Log.d("writeData:", "streamsOpened");

    oOut.writeInt(this.targetINR);
    oOut.writeObject(this.inrReadings);
    oOut.writeObject(this.weeklyDoses);
    oOut.writeObject(this.alarmTime);
    Log.d("writeData:", "objectsWritten");
    oOut.close();
    fOut.close();
    Log.d("writeData:", "Streams closed, write finished");

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[]{"/data/data/" + "com.example.yourpackage" + "/config" }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                }
            });

    return;
}
```

And the `loadData` function should be.

```
private void loadData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Will run and load all data from the config file into the app's memory
    Log.d("READ:", "reading starting");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/data/data/" + "com.example.yourpackage" + "/config");
    ObjectInputStream oIS = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
    Object[] output = new Object[4];

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        output[i] = oIS.readObject();
        Log.d("READ:", output[i].toString());
    }

    oIS.close();
    fileInputStream.close();

    return;
}
```

Replace `com.example.yourpackage` with the package name that you have for your project.